# Как добавить CSS классы в PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

У меня есть работающий слайдер, там показывает 4 видео, мне нужно чтобы когда заходить через мобильное устройство показывало картинку, когда через десктоп то видео, слайдер написан на JS, нашел скрипт `isMobile`, с ее помощью могу определить с какого устройство заходит юзер

```
.player__video {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}
```

теперь проблема в том как css класс соединить с php файлом, чтобы в php файле отображался видео в слайдере;

```
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';

    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;

    // Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
    if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {

    }


// Any tablet device.
if( $detect->isTablet() ){

}
```

скрипт ismobile

```
<div class="hero__player">
              <div class="player">

                                    <?php

                                      $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
                                      if($detect->isMobile()){
                                         $tr= '<img src="/templates/assets/images/button_ground_test.jpg" style="width:100%;">';
                                         $poster="[xfvalue_videopathimage]";
                                            if($poster=="/templates/assets/images/car.jpg"){
                                              echo $ec;
                                            }else if($poster=="/templates/assets/images/health.jpg"){
                                              echo $tr;
                                            }else if($poster=="/templates/assets/images/property.jpg"){
                                               echo $ec;
                                            }else if($poster=="/templates/assets/images/travel.jpg"){
                                                echo $tr;
                                            }

                                      }else{
                                        echo '<video class="player__video" width="506" height="506" muted preload="auto" playsinline poster="[xfvalue_videopathimage]"> <source src="[xfvalue_videopath]" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag. </video>';

                                      }
                                  ?>
```

код в tpl

Comment: html-разметку слайдера покажите

Comment: @humster_spb слайдер оказывается работает в js файле, и подключен в main.tpl(template), можно ли в этом случае что то изменить?

Comment: @Arsen Ospanov у вас ведь есть tpl в нем и делайте то что нужно.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev какие классы должен подключать? то что в JS?

Comment: @Arsen Ospanov я не ясновидящий. У вас нет конкретного примера кода на выходе. Но, если есть tpl-файлы, то лезть в php для добавления классов - не надо. Достаточно прописать в tpl.

Comment: @VladimirRodichev добавил

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте этот

```
<?if ( $detect->isMobile() ):?>
<style>
.player__video {
     overflow: hidden;
     max-width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     vertical-align: top;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}
</style>

<div class="player__video">

</div>

<?endif;?>
```